# I want to find a string in other string, in python like "Microsoft Edge" in str, but find is not working, index is not working

Tags: python-3.x

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
import time
import re
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    window = GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())
    #print(type(window))
    #print(window)
    string = 'Microsoft Edge'
    if re.search() >= 0:
       print(1)
    time.sleep
```

I am trying to check what app is running in foreground to print

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   That isn't how you use ```re.search()```.  Please read up https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search.  Please include sample input and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have `pywin32`installed. You may try this approach

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
import time
import re
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    window = GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())
    #print(type(window))
    #print(window)
    string = 'Microsoft Edge'
    #if re.search() >= 0:
       #print(1)
    if re.search(string, window):
       print(string, 'Found')
    else:
       print(string, 'NOT Found')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Also, in the last statement, i have added `(1)`. Hope this works for you. Further, you need to be careful with the loop because it is running indefinetly. You must place a control statement to exit.